# Error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' en Angular con Socket.io

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, cors

Hola estoy haciendo un app con Socket.io en un servidor con express: mi servidor es el siguiente:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('./socket-config')(http);
const cors = require('cors');
app.io = io;

app.use(cors({
   methods:['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE','OPTIONS'],
   credentials: true,
   allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Authorization'],
   origin: '*'
}));

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
console.log('Cliente conectado: '+socket.id);})

http.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Como se puedo ver primero configuro e importo las librerias archivos etc, des pues configuro el cors para las request de cualquier origen, y finalmente creo una instancia para saber si el cliente se conecto con exito!

En Angular en un servicio `socket.service.ts` hago lo siguiente:

```
socket:any
server:string = 'http://localhost:3000'

constructor() {
  this.socket = io(this.server), { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] };
}
connectSocket(){
  this.socket.connect()
}
```

Este servicio lo inyecto en `app.component.ts` y unicamente inicio la funcion para conectar

Dandome como resultado el sigiente error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrRaS0f' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Y no se cual seria ya el problema, en angular ya esta cargado el http client module por lo que las peticiones ya las hace y en el backend se supone que ya permite el origen o algo no entendi?